# Picking maximum value from multiple rows in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, max

I have a data frame which has information for 15 sites with 10 values/per site. In total I have thirty values of tree diameters per site. 
I want to measure the maximum value out of these thirty values by comparing the value of the diameters in all the columns in each of these sites.

I have grouped the data by site.

My dataframe contains the following columns 
Name of Site, Dia.1, Dia.2 and Dia.3.

```
structure(list(ï..Site.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "But", class = "factor"), 
X1.27324062 = c(1.27324062, 2.228171085, 2.54648124, 2.228171085, 
3.501411706), X0.63662031 = c(1.27324062, 0.954930465, 1.27324062, 
1.591550775, 0.318310155), X1.27324062.1 = c(1.27324062, 
0.63662031, 2.864791395, 1.591550775, 1.90986093)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
```

-5L))

I have attempted using the apply function and pmax functions, they provide me the answer per row across the three columns, however I am trying to compare the values per cell across the thirty values in each site.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output for the same. Read this post for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: Show your input data and how you tried with `apply`?

Comment: @RonakShah: Thank you for the link, I did try to create a dataframe which is the way in which most other people put out their data, but, my data is grouped and somehow the read.table--Text function also had not worked. Can you please let me know if this is alright, or how I can modify it?

Comment: usually you use `dput` to share data. Type `dput(dataframe_name)` in your console and post the output here. Also make the example minimal. So for example, if you have 15 sites with 10 values/per site can you create a fake dataset with 3 sites and 5 values per site and show your expected output here ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Is this alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Site_Id` is your first column you can `split` the data based on it and select the `max` value from all the values of the column.

```
sapply(split(df[-1], df[[1]]), function(x) max(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE))

#  But 
#3.5014
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is x in this? and I am guessing df is the dataframe right?

Comment: @KeerthiKrutha yes, `df` is the dataframe that you have. `x` is used as an argument to anonymous function for `sapply`.

Comment: Thank you Ronak I think I got the max. values but I also got the following "Warning message:
In max(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"- What does this mean?